# Jetpack Compose Access Room Database

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to get some database objects from Room inside of a composable function. Currently when I try to call:

```
@Composable
fun loadDashboard() {

    val db = DatabaseService.getDatabase(null)
        
    val userDao = db.userDao()
    val userModel = userDao.getOne()
}
```

I receive an error:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`

Is there a best practice solution for accessing the database in this situation so I can get data to make an API call?

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5), will help.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to create a repository class and do database operations there.
You can return a flow from the get method of the repository and emit the result when the operation is done. This flow can then be collected by a viewmodel inside a coroutine that is dispatched on the IO thread. When the result is collected, store it inside a state that is observed by the composable.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `userDao.getOne()` function to **suspending** function and call it from ViewModel inside a scope, ViewModel has [viewModelScope](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/easy-coroutines-in-android-viewmodelscope-25bffb605471) by default, or your custom scope, this makes testing easy.

If you don't want to use ViewModel or repo, you can simply call this function inside `LaunchedEffect` by calling your function in its lambda.

Or `produceState` functions of Compose

Data with loading, success or error states with produceState for instance is as

```
@Composable
private fun getOneFromDb(): State<Result> {


    return produceState<Result>(initialValue = Result.Loading) {

        // In a coroutine, can make suspend calls
        val one = db.getOne()

        // Update State with either an Error or Success result.
        // This will trigger a recomposition where this State is read
        value = if (one == null) {
            Result.Error
        } else {
            Result.Success(one)
        }
    }
}

val oneState = getOneFromDb()

sealed class Result {
    object Loading : Result()
    object Error : Result()
    class Success(val one: OneModel) : Result()
}
```